# Bash: Sum of integer values from stdout

Tags: bash, integer, sum, cut

Is there a way to do this?

I have a set of data which includes an integer field:

```
cat myinput
14 bytes long.
36 bytes long.
32 bytes long.
```

I would like to add the integer values in these text lines to give a sum total. So in the case of the above example, the sum total of the integer values is 82. I had thought of using something like:

```
cat myinput | cut -f1 -d' ' | <...add code here to add the filtered integers...>
```

It seems I have to expr in some way, but I can't figure out how.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's do it with awk?

```
$ awk 'a+=$1; END{print a}' file
14 bytes long.
36 bytes long.
32 bytes long.
82
```

With bash:

```
f=0
while read i
do
  n=$(echo $i | cut -d' ' -f1)
  tot=$(($n + $tot))
done < file

$ echo $tot
82
```

Comment: Many thanks. I like the awk solution. Strangely, when I pipe the text input into your awk expression using "cat file | awk ...", the extracted integer inputs are echoed on the output, finally followed by the result.

Comment: See that the `awk` expression does not need `cat`: the input file is indicated after the command.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: In my case, the input to the awk command doesn't come from a file; instead, it is piped into awk from a series of piped bash commands: cat file | grep ... | cut ... | awk ... In any case, thanks again, wak did the job.

Comment: OK, now I see. Then for example `cat file | ... | awk 'a+=$1; END{print a}'` should work to you. Cheers!